Using WSL1 on visual studio 2022
I'm running LTSC build 1809 with a WSL Debian distro.  I have VS2022 installed and not able to debug a project using the WSL profile because it says there is no distro installed.  Do I have to install a 2017 or perhaps 2019 VS to run this?
Not able to change WSL versions since my build does not support WSL2.  Below is the usage info for my wsl.exe
Usage: wsl.exe [option] ...
Options:
    -d, --distribution <DistributionName>
        Launch the specified distribition.

    -e, --exec <CommandLine>
        Execute the specified Linux command. The remainder of the arguments are
        used as the command line to execute.

    -u, --user <UserName>
        Run as the specified user.

    --help
        Display this usage information.

    --
        Stop parsing arguments and pass the remainder to the Linux process.

LaunchSettings.json has the following:
{
  "profiles": {
    "ConsoleApp1": {
      "commandName": "Project"
    },
    "WSL:Debian": {
      "commandName": "WSL2",
      "distributionName": "Debian"
    }
  }
}

Changing the commandName to "WSL" renders a warning stating that only xxx choices are allowed to include: WSL2, IIS, Docker, Prject, etc...
My Debian install seems to work.  I installed GCC and ran some C just fine.  I'm trying to debug .NET like this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-dotnet-core-in-wsl-2?view=vs-2022

I do want to point out that I'm using VS2022 17.10.  According to the link above the commandName target for WSL2 was changed to WSL beginning with 2019 16.10 preview 3.  Going to "repair" my installation.
